# Required to include all feature modules in app Module in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to figure out how they are getting away with no including two major modules (CrisisCenterModule and AdminModule) in the app.module in this example:

https://stackblitz.com/angular/moybyqrjdeom

Is it not required to add feature modules to app.module? In most cases people do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are using [lazy load module](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules) in route. And yes, you don't need to import to App module. Router will do it for you

```js
{
  path: 'admin',
  loadChildren: 'app/admin/admin.module#AdminModule',
  canLoad: [AuthGuard]
}
```

This is useful in large projects that have many child modules, and you don't want to load all pages once. Under the hood, the project's source code will be compiled into many `js` files corresponded to each module. They will be downloaded and initialized the first time you go to module's route.

In small sized projects, loading all modules once doesn't take much time though. And lazy loading can be slower because of network latency.